# Два вложенных цикла while.Как вернуться на предыдущий шаг?

Tags: java, while

помогите понять, пожалуйста.

**Дано:**

```
первый цикл while(true){

Условие1

if (условие 1 соблюдено)

второй цикл: while (true){

Условие 2
}
if (Условие 2 НЕ соблюдено)

Вернуть пользователя не на первый while,  а на второй?

}
```

**Вот настоящий код**

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<String> taskArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        
        while (true){
            System.out.println("Выберите действие:\n" +
                    "1. Добавить задачу\n" +
                    "2. Вывести список задач\n" +
                    "3. Удалить задачу\n" +
                    "0. Выход\n");
            
            String enter = scanner.nextLine();
            if (enter.equals("0")){
                System.out.println("Вы закончили");
                break;
            }if (enter.equals("1")){
        
                boolean x =true;
                while (x == true){
                    System.out.println("Введите задачу:");
                    String enter2 = scanner.nextLine();
    
                    if (enter2.length() < 5){
                        System.out.println("Задача не может быть пустой или состоять меньше чем из 4 символов");
                      x=false;
            

        //  throw new Exception("Задача не может быть пустой или состоять меньше чем из 4 символов");
                }
            }
            
        
            
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: А условия впервые задаются в `if` или ранее? Если только в `if`, то почему бы просто тогда не записать `if (условие 1 соблюдено || условие 2 НЕ соблюдено) { while(true) {} }`, объединив два условия в одно?

Comment: 4500zenja к сожалению это я упростил, там условия с подусловиями.

Comment: Пусть даже и условия с подусловиями, их все равно можно записать на месте первого if и разделить их `||`, а второй `if` вообще убрать

Comment: вы так и останетесь во втором вайле если второе условие не выполнится, просто уберите приравнивание икса к false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<String> taskArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
   
    
    while (true){
        System.out.println("Выберите действие:\n1. Добавить задачу\n2. Вывести список задач\n3. Удалить задачу\n0. Выход\n");
       

        
        int enter = scanner.nextInt();
        if (enter == 0){
            System.out.println("Вы закончили");
            break;
        }else if (enter == 1){
    
            boolean x = true;
            while (x){
                System.out.println("Введите задачу:");
                String enter2 = scanner.nextLine();

                if (enter2.length() < 5){
                    System.out.println("Задача не может быть пустой или состоять меньше чем из 4 символов");
                  
            }else{
                x = false;
            }
        }
        
    
        
    }
}}}
```

Попробуйте вот так сделать. В этом коде есть отличие - вместо scanner.nextLine() я поставил scanner.nextInt() думаю разницы нету.

Но если вы хотите после "Задача не может быть пустой или состоять меньше чем из 4 символов" вот такого исключения остаться на втором while то x = false надо поставить в другое условие

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно условие вопроса.

Но попробую ответить исходя из своих догадок: второй вайл вы можете выделить в функцию отдельную и запускать его исходя из ваших условий